# When solving for $x$ where $x$ is raised to $n$ why doesn’t dividing both sides by $x^{n-1}$ work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example,

$x^2+1=0$

In this instance, taking the square root of both sides produces $+i$ and $-i$

But why is it not valid to divide both sides by $x^{n-1}$ i.e. by $x$?  Since $x^2=x \times x$, why is it not the case that we can divide by $x$ on both sides and create product $x=-1/x$?  This negative reciprocal of $x$ is not equal to $\pm i$, so clearly I am wrong, but I’m having difficulty seeing where my logic is failing.

Why is this method invalid?

Comment: It is valid, since $x$ is obviously not 0, but it doesn't lead you anywhere

Comment: Specifically, the solutions of $x=-1/x$ are $i$ and $-i$. Verifying that these are solutions is just a matter of plugging them into the equation. Verify that there are no other solutions is best done by multiplying both sides of the equation by $x$ to get back to $x^2+1=0$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is hard to follow as written. What is $n$? The question-writer can and should do better than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is valid in the sense that you're allowed to do it and it leads to a true expression since $x \neq 0$, but it doesn't get you anywhere closer to solving the equation.

The point of writing $x^2 + 1 = 0$ as $x^2 = -1$ is so we can express the unknown quantity in terms of known quantities only. Your "method" does not allow that.

Comment: Thanks Victor.  You are right.  I lost sight of the end-goal.